# MySQL left join + performance

Tags: mysql

```
        SELECT  

            *    #Case 1
            cp.* #Case 2

        FROM crawl_page AS cp
        LEFT JOIN artist AS a
            ON cp.cpURL LIKE CONCAT('%',a.artistPageID,'/',a.artistPageURL,'%')

        WHERE cpPageType = 'SONGS'
            AND cpPageAdded < (
                SELECT cpCrawlDate 
                FROM crawl_page 
                WHERE cpURL = 'http://www.example.com/page-52/'
            )

            AND a.artistID IS NULL  

        LIMIT 1
```

In this query when I use 1st case (selecting everything from both tables) time taken for query is fine about 0.468 sec.

But if I do case 2 (selecting only from main table) it takes hell much time 26 second.

It's not problem just to use case 1, but I can't get the idea how does it work and why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried executing the commands in different orders?  (doing case 2 first, for example).  MySQL will cache queries, so subsequent queries when the data hasn't changed will be much faster.

Comment: Sure I tried, I do them separately.

Comment: I dont see a reason for what you describe.  You might want to do an EXPLAIN in mysql to see if there's anything different in the execution of the statement.